# Tracking ownership/ancestor-hierarchies/group-membership via annotations/bytecode-weaving?

Tags: java, annotations, aop, relationship, bytecode-manipulation

In GUI frameworks it's common to track parent/child relationships explicitly - given an arbitrary GUI component one can navigate up through the hierarchy of components that "own" it.

The parent components aren't necessarily the entities that actually created their children, these relationships are typically configured after creation.

I have a situation in which it's the creation relationships that I'm interested in, i.e. that one object created another.

The objects involved belong to distinct classes and there is generally no inheritance relationship or such like between them.

Really I create "master" objects that have an id, and I want all objects that are created by these objects (either directly or at n-degrees of separation) to know the id of their particular "master" object.

[ The id is actually only of interest for logging purposes. ]

I could imagine something like this:

```
public class Master
{
    @GroupId
    private final long id;
}

@InheritGroupId
public class Foo
{
    public void bar()
    {
        logger.info("I belong to group {}", XXX);
    }
}
```

For the Master object the id would be set in its constructor. Any class that was marked with @InheritGroupId would on construction *somehow* look up the stack and look for the first caller object that either knew its group-id directly via the @GroupId annotation or had determined it in the same fashion as this class, i.e. one that was also marked with @InheritGroupId.

How you would then access the group-id value I'm not sure, in the above code I've just used XXX in the place where I'd like to access it.

I say "*somehow* look up the stack", but as far as I know it's not possible to inspect the stack like this in straight Java.

Maybe an alternative construction that doesn't require stack inspection is possible. Or maybe some kind of AOP byte-weaving approach is possible?

At the moment I pass groupId as an explicit constructor argument to nearly every object in my system. It seems a shame to me that all objects must maintain a member variable that isn't really part of their logic but is used purely for logging.

Passing groupId explicitly does have the advantage of clearly pointing up situations where establishing a creator relationship between something low down and one of my "master" objects is difficult.

If you have any ideas how to handle what I've described with annotations or byte-code weaving, or you think passing group-ids explicitly actually is the best way, or you have some completely different idea as to how to achieve much the same thing, then please tell me.

/George

**Update:** note that all "child" objects, of a given master object, are *not* all created up front at one given point in time, i.e. it's not a matter of simply setting the group-id into some singleton and then having the child objects access this singleton in some way as they are created en masse.

Comment: Interesting problem. I'm not aware of any way to look up the stack, but there is such a thing as a [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html), and if you can weave in code, you could set one whenever execution passes through an object that has a group ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [a per-control-flow aspect](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-aspects.html#d0e7099). Each time you enter a method in the pointcut, an instance of the aspect is created. Each time you exit the control flow, it becomes unreferenced. It is inherently thread-local and it will be created exactly when you want to initialize it. This is just a sketch, but I think you would want something like:

```
aspect GetId percflow(callsFromMaster()) {

    private long id;

    pointcut callsFromMaster() : within(Master.*);
    pointcut childConstructors() : cflow(callsFromMaster()) && execution(Foo.new.(..));

    before(Master master) : callsFromMaster() && this(master) {
        this.id = master.getId();
    }

    after(Foo child) : childConstructors() && this(child) {
        child.id = this.id;
    }

}
```

Which I would read as: Each time you enter the control flow of a call from a Master method, create a new instance of this aspect. Before each of those calls, save the ID. Within that same control flow, each time a new Foo is created copy the ID from the current Master to the new Foo.